# How do I set up PHP configuration?

Tags: drush

I am running websites on my PC with following php5:

> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

(this is what I can see when running phpinfo() command within website php code).

How to set Drush, so it would use the same php version?

I found [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1302418) which says, that I should detect, where is my bin/php file in my PC and set it in DRUSH_PHP environment variable.
I have found following files:

> ./usr/bin/php
>
> ./usr/bin/php5

although, when I set this as DRUSH_PHP variable (in ~/.bashrc file), my drush would stop work at all. Otherwise, without this setting of variable, I can run drush commands, that does not need PHP to run.

Can anybody help, how to proceed, to set the same php version for drush as it is used by website in phpinfo()?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify different PHP when running drush, e.g.

```
DRUSH_PHP=/path/to/php drush cr
```

In my configuration I've created the following symbolic (such as `php71` and `php72`):

```
/usr/local/bin/php71 -> /usr/local/opt/php71/bin/php
/usr/local/bin/php72 -> /usr/local/opt/php72/bin/php
```

in the local `bin/` folder which is in my `PATH`, so the commands are accessible.

Then I can run drush using different PHP version like:

```
DRUSH_PHP=php71 drush status
```

or:

```
DRUSH_PHP=php72 drush status
```

---

If you'd like to add `DRUSH_PHP` globally, add it to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` like:

```
export DRUSH_PHP=/full/path/to/php
```

Alternatively make sure your php path is in your `PATH` before any other versions.

To check whether you've multiple PHP version in your `PATH`, run this command:

```
which -a php
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent half a day trying to re-install drush 8.x
Finally stumbled on documentation for 7.x that fixed the 8.x problem.

Symptomatically, the PHP configuration came back blank. And as no surprise, DRUSH blew up when I attempted to run it within a Drupal instance.

```
 PHP configuration      :
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush
 Drush version          :  8.1.17
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
```

The answer was found [HERE](http://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/configure/)

I am running MAMP with PHP 7.2.1. So the PATH should be as shown below. That fixed the problem - finally!

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin:$PATH
```